# How have both local and remote variable inside an SSH command locally available

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

This is a variation of the question here: [How have both local and remote variable inside an SSH command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826149/how-have-both-local-and-remote-variable-inside-an-ssh-command)

How do I get the "ssh-variable" B to my local computer?

```
 A=3
 ssh host@name "echo $A; B=5; echo $A; echo \$B;"
 echo $A
 echo $B
 echo \$B
```

returns 3, NOTHING, $B

How can I locally access a value for B?

some explanations based on comments:
I am using a bash script to access a remote host to modify some things there, amongst other things create a workspace there. The location of this workspace is what I want to store in a variable and save for later use.

Basically, I have a function to go to the remote host and make the workspace and then another function to use the path to that workspace to do other things there.

I was hoping for a lightweight, slim solution that can be integrated and easily read in a command similar to this:

```
 ssh host@name "ws_allocate myworkspace; workspace=ws_find myworkspace;"
```

and then locally use $workspace. This is part of a larger bash script, that should be easy to understand for non-expert bash users (like myself)...

Turns out this is a duplicate of [bash—Better way to store variable between runs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334495/bash-better-way-to-store-variable-between-runs)

Comment: You can save the content of the remote variable in a file, and then recover the file content in your localhost.

Comment: this waaay too complicated for my purpose ;)

Comment: Why? Write a local script, scp to upload the local script in the remote server, ssh to execute the script and store result in a /tmp file (in the remote server), scp to download the response, and then process the answer locally.

Comment: Think about it: you want a variable defined by a remote shell to be defined in your local shell. That's some significant interprocess communication; it's not going to be simple.

Comment: On the other hand, if your example is accurate and the assignment statement is hard-coded in the argument to `ssh`, why don't you just define it locally to begin with?

Comment: I'll add some text to my answer below, as a reaction to your edit

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

`X=$(ssh user@host 'echo $X')`

This will run `echo $X` on the server and place the resulting output in a local variable X, which you can later use by saying `$X`

So to apply this to your example, you could say:

```
workspace=$(ssh host@name 'ws_allocate myworkspace; ws_find myworkspace;')
```

Note that the local variable `workspace` will contain the output from the command that is run remotely. So I'm assuming that in your example **only** the `ws_find myworkspace` will print any output and that the call to `ws_allocate` is silent.

Comment: C=$(ssh user@host "echo $B"); echo $C   empty output

Comment: This is because you are using double quotes `"echo $B"`. Try using single quotes: `'echo $B'`

Comment: can it bee that B is lost when ssh disconnects and therefore is not available when I connect again to save it in C with echo?

Comment: Yes; if you made the variable in a previous ssh session it will not be available in the next session. But in that case I also don't get the point of doing this, please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks, I have learnt a lot (again). In my example, this will not work out I am afraid (see my answer below)

Answer (score -2):

Ok, so the  solution that appears to me to be the easiest and that allows the value of $B to be stored on the remote host is to save it in a file. As described and discussed here already: [bash—Better way to store variable between runs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334495/bash-better-way-to-store-variable-between-runs) :(

```
ssh ${supercomputer} "
ws_list -a >workspaces.txt;
if grep -q "${experiment}" workspaces.txt; 
then echo 'we have a workspace already'; 
else ws_allocate ${experiment} 30; 
fi; 
ws_find ${experiment} > mypathtoworkspace;"
```

where supercomputer is the address to the host, experiment the workspace I want to create (or not, if it is there already) and workspace the workspace I want to create for my experiment.

I wanted to use the path to the remote workspace locally, e.g.

```
 echo "${workspace}"
```

but this seems to not be possible - therefore I will download the file I am writing on the remote host and read the path from that file to use it locally

If anyone sees a better solution it is welcome!

Comment: This does not make sense to me. Your question is about getting a remote variable to the local machine, and the answer is to store a local value on the remote machine?

Comment: it is a remote value that is stored on the remote machine. I am not leaving my remote host in this ssh command

Comment: I see. Do you agree that this is not what the question is about?

Comment: in the overall context it is, in the context of the answer maybe not